# MySQL INNER JOIN on the same tables

Tags: mysql

I have a system where all the users are stored in the same table and their "role" decides what kind of user they are.

Customers earn points at stores. I am trying to create a PHP page where the customer can see which store they have earned their points and so stores can log in and see which Customers have earned points. (Hope that makes sense!)

I have two tables

Table1 is the user table and contains all the user information in it.. i.e Name, Address, etc

Table2 stores all the points and the uid (which is the customer ID) and the SID (which is the store id) both these fields match the uid in the user table.

sooo....

I think the MySQL needs to look something like this

```
Select loyal_tokens.tokens, loyal_tokens.date, users.id, users.email, users.first_name, users.last_name,loyal_tokens.sid,loyal_tokens.uid from users, loyal_tokens
INNER JOIN loyal_tokens, users as StoresName on users.id = loyal_tokens.sid 
INNER JOIN loyal_tokens, users as UsersName on users.id = loyal_tokens.uid
```

This doesn't work (obviously as there are non-unique tables). I am really at a loss on how to fix it!

At the end of the SQL, I will be putting a where clause

```
WHERE users.id=x
```

The user id could be either a store or a customer and it will display the points that they have earned and display the store/customer name rather than the ID.

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Michael

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left join`, e.g.:

```
SELECT lt.*, u1.*, u2.*
FROM loyal_tokens lt LEFT JOIN users u1 ON lt.uid = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON lt.sid = u2.id
WHERE lt.sid = ? OR lt.uid = ?
```

Based on values returned by `u1.*` and `u2.*`, you can check whether it's a store or customer and display the values accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a much better way of doing it!

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I have a bit of a follow up question, the query returns all the fields which is great, but because I am matching against the same tables the same field names come up... how do I "address" the second field. I would have thought it would have been u1.first_name and u2.first_name, but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: You could use `u1.address AS "customer_address", u2.address AS "store_address"` etc, instead of using `u1.*`

Answer (score 0):

Use a syntax like this for querying the customers for a certain store

```
Select 
     loyal_tokens.tokens, loyal_tokens.date, 
     customer.last_name, customer.first_name
from loyal_tokens
    left join users as customer on customer.id = loyal_tokens.uid 
where loyal_tokens.sid  = 1234
```

You need a different equivalent query for getting the stores for a customer. You can't use the same query for both features.

Comment: Darshan's answer pointed me in the right direction, fortunately on the php page I have the ability to see which role is assigned to the user and then can use two different SQL statements one is based on lt.sid and one on lt.uid